# Styling Ransack attribute_fields Select2 Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack, select2-rails

I'm trying to style the select button from [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/) with the [Select2 plugin](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails).

```
  <%= f.attribute_fields do |a| %>
    <%= a.attribute_select %>
  <% end %>
```

That's generating and HTML output of:

```
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name" name="q[c][0][a][0][name]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="points">Points</option>
  <option value="town_count">Town count</option>
  <option value="rank">Rank</option>
</select>
```

But somehow i can't find a way to assign to the `attribute_fields` the id `'select'`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through [Ransack_UI](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/ransack_ui) i found this:

```
<%= f.attribute_fields do |a| %>
  <%= a.attribute_select({}, :id => 'select') %>
<% end %>
```